# find the probability that, in the next 7 weeks, there are exactly 3 weeks in which Jan receives exactly 2 free gifts

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can you give me a breakdown of the stages you take arriving at the answer to the following question: Jan buys $5$ packets per week with a $30\%$ chance of finding a gift per packet,find the probability that, in the next $7$ weeks, there are exactly $3$ weeks in which Jan receives exactly $2$ free gifts.

I start by finding the probability of exactly $2$ free gifts:
$5C2 \times (0.30)^2 \times (0.7)^3 = 0.3087$

Then I start by using that answer to find the two gifts in $3$ weeks out of $7$:
$7C3 \times (0.3087)^3 \times (1-0.3087)^4$  -- But to me this seems like we are finding $2$ free gifts per week for $3$ weeks instead of exactly $2$ free gifts in $3$ weeks...

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. You are finding the probability that out of 7 weeks, there are exactly 3 weeks in which she wins exactly 2 prizes. Isn't that what you want?
This does of course include the possibility that in some of these weeks she does win a different number of prizes, or indeed none at all.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I was thinking exactly 2 free gifts over 3 weeks -- which wouldn't make sense -- instead of 3 out of the 7 weeks where she receives exactly 2 free gifts per week for 3 weeks.